# Disadvantages of using Entity Framework in cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datacontext

Sometimes I put some of my C# code in my view (`.cshtml`) not all of my code. For example I have a table named **LawCategory** and I do this:

```
@{
  var db = new Contracts.Models.DataContext();
  var LawCat = db.LawCategory.ToList();    
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>category:</label>
            <select name="Type" id="Type" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">All</option>
                @foreach (var i in LawCat)
                {
                    <option value="@i.ID" @(Request.QueryString["id"] == i.ID.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@i.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
```

I want to know what is disadvantages of using datacontext in view and connect to database instead of send view model from controller?

Is it true that doing this, may cause set multi connection to database? (Entity Framework)

Comment: Its poor design. Hypothetically you could write an entire application using only a single method with 1000's of lines of code BUT you shouldn't because its poor design. The view should be concerned only with presentation logic, interaction with data stores should be done in the Controller or further down the call stack.

Comment: Opinion-based. Not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DBContext (EntityFramework) code directly in View as it is allowed and execute perfectly.

Now problem comes with design and MVC pattern itself.

1. In MVC pattern , we mostly use for separation of concern. Here view has more than one concern apart from managing view. It directly call EntityFramework and so it break that point.
2. It make code less testable. As here we also want to look at each view as view might contains some code and that not specified in Controller so by looking at controller only we can not identify dependency.

Comment: So there is no concern about multi connection to database?

Comment: That depends. Lets assume that you want to get more than one table record using EF and you call Entity framework in View and use same to get multiple data then not issue but issue with design and pattern will be there.

Comment: So let's assume that i used a EF connection in my action too, is there a problem in this case? one connection in my action that returns my view and another connection in my view

Comment: I said it is upto developer and SQL server allow two connection. Connection to DB is not problem. If you want inside one connection you can move code to Action of Controller but It is up to developer but design and pattern point of view this code consider bad not because it has made connection to DB but View has logic other than UI or presentation.

Comment: Thanks , one last question. according to what is said, if i use EF in action and view, is it going to reduce the performance?

Comment: Yes. As you make two different call to DB but not much but keep connection close/dispose as soon as you done with your work.

Comment: If it clear your understanding then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you breaking the MVC pattern, you need to separate the Model, business logci (Controller) and the rendered View and that for many reasons (read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Second, if your are building a web application you need to take in consideration that there are rules to follow (if you want to do it the right way). Here you need to build and manage your Business Layer (mainly your data model) then you can choose whatever pattern to use in your Presentation Layer (MVC for your case). Learn more about 3-tier architecture here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/4d9083/create-and-implement-3-tier-architecture-in-asp-net/

Third, playing with C# and .NET is cool and helpful to learn but if you want to build professional web applications you need to learn a lot about software design patterns. Here a good book 'Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software'